# Empty json array is being returned while retrieving values from gson

Tags: android, arrays, gson, android-sharedpreferences

Following is my POJO class

```
public class Favourite {
    public static List<LocalTrack> favourite;

    public Favourite() {
        favourite = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<LocalTrack> getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }
}
```

Im saving the json as follows in my shared preference

public static class SaveFavourites extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String json5 = gson.toJson(favourite);
        prefsEditor.putString("favouriteTracks", json5);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Following are the fields which refers to POJO class

public static Favourite    favouriteTracks =new Favourite();
    public  static List favourite = favouriteTracks.getFavourite();

Im using the following class to access the json stored as follows,

```
String json5 = mPrefs.getString("favouriteTracks", "");
Arrays.toString(gson.fromJson(json5, Favourite[].class))
```

But it always returns empty array though it was not empty while saving. When im saving, it has got a json array with multiple json  objects but while retrieving, it is an empty json array.

How can I be able to sort this out?

Following is my json response

```
[
  {
    "album": "http://MyMp3Song.Com",
    "artist": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakka",
    "index": "#",
    "path": "/storage/sdcard1/Download/04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com).mp3",
    "title": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com)",
    "duration": 369424,
    "id": 32004
  },
  {
    "album": "http://MyMp3Song.Com",
    "artist": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakka",
    "index": "#",
    "path": "/storage/sdcard1/Download/04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com).mp3",
    "title": "04 - Thai Mannai Vanakkam(MyMp3Song.Com)",
    "duration": 369424,
    "id": 32004
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add your JSON reponse.

Comment: I have added the json response

Comment: any ideas?,,,,,

Comment: sorry for the late, is your problem solved?

Comment: Ya ofcourse..I have created a custom db to save java objects directly. I used my custom db to store and retrieve objects. using my object,I was able to retrieve all datas. It works like a charm by now. If only i wouldn't have faced this issue, I wouldn't have come up with a newer db for android. glad that i faced this issue. currently Im enhancing the db